# Mysql SUM changes (to incorrect value) when adding ANY_VALUE to the select fields

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I have a query, and I'm stumped as to why the `SUM` function is returning seemingly incorrect results when I add an additional (functionally dependent) field to the `GROUP BY`. Even when not changing the `GROUP BY`, and using `ANY_VALUE`, it still suddenly changes the `SUM` result.

The query is quite long, but for brevity, I'll only include the relevant part. I have not included `cte` which is a recursive query, but not relevant to the question. The example later on in, shows the full results of data regardless of what `cte` is.

```
select
cte.Id,
       YEAR(A.CreatedAt)                                                `Year`,
       MONTH(A.CreatedAt)                                               `Month`,
       (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(SR.AgencyProductionRevenue * SA.Split), 0)) `TotalRevenue`
from cte
         JOIN NetworkMembers `member` ON cte.Id = `member`.Id
         JOIN AccountTransactions A ON (
            `member`.AccountId = A.AccountId AND A.PaymentPeriodId is not null
        AND (A.CreatedAt > '2020-02-01')
    
    
    )
         LEFT JOIN SaleRevenue SR on A.SaleRevenueId = SR.Id
         LEFT JOIN SaleAgents SA
                   ON (SA.SaleId = SR.SaleId AND SA.NetworkMemberId = `member`.Id AND SA.SaleId is not null)
GROUP BY cte.Id, YEAR(A.CreatedAt), MONTH(A.CreatedAt);
```

This produces a result with a record:

| Id | Year | Month | TotalRevenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 08d87138-676a-48b8-85c0-4692d914fdf2 | 2021 | 11 | -37.470000000000006 |

However, when I add `ANY_VALUE(cte.ParentId)`, suddenly the resulting `SUM` for the same grouping is changed:

| Id | ParentId | Year | Month | TotalRevenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 08d87138-676a-48b8-85c0-4692d914fdf2 | NULL | 2021 | 11 | -1.2999999999999998 |

In my case, `ParentId` is functionally dependent on `Id`, I've even proved this by removing the `GROUP BY` and `SUM` clause and dumping out all records. For all records, whenever `Id` = `08d87138-676a-48b8-85c0-4692d914fdf2` then `ParentId` is `NULL`. I also tried adding `ParentId` to my `GROUP BY`:

```
GROUP BY cte.Id, cte.ParentId, YEAR(A.CreatedAt), MONTH(A.CreatedAt)
```

This produces the same incorrect sum in the second table above, even though `ParentId` is functionally dependent on `Id`.

To verify, that`SUM` is wrong in the second table above, I can select ALL records with the following clause:

```
WHERE cte.Id = '08d87138-676a-48b8-85c0-4692d914fdf2' AND YEAR(A.CreatedAt) = 2021 AND MONTH(A.CreatedAt) = 11
```

Here is the full query:

```
select cte.Id,
       YEAR(A.CreatedAt)                                                `Year`,
       MONTH(A.CreatedAt)                                               `Month`,
       COALESCE(SR.AgencyProductionRevenue * SA.Split,0),
        cte.ParentId
    
from cte
         JOIN NetworkMembers `member` ON cte.Id = `member`.Id
         JOIN AccountTransactions A ON (
            `member`.AccountId = A.AccountId AND A.PaymentPeriodId is not null
        AND (A.CreatedAt > '2020-02-01')
    )
         LEFT JOIN SaleRevenue SR on A.SaleRevenueId = SR.Id
         LEFT JOIN SaleAgents SA
                   ON (SA.SaleId = SR.SaleId AND SA.NetworkMemberId = `member`.Id AND SA.SaleId is not null)
WHERE cte.Id = '08d87138-676a-48b8-85c0-4692d914fdf2' AND YEAR(A.CreatedAt) = 2021 AND MONTH(A.CreatedAt) = 11
GROUP BY cte.Id, cte.ParentId, YEAR(A.CreatedAt), MONTH(A.CreatedAt)
```

Here is the full results. Manually summing the `COALESCE` column gives the correct result of `-37.470000000000006`.

| Id | Year | Month | COALESCE(SR.AgencyProductionRevenue * SA.Split,0) | ParentId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 08d87138-676a-48b8-85c0-4692d914fdf2 | 2021 | 11 | 0 | NULL |
| 08d87138-676a-48b8-85c0-4692d914fdf2 | 2021 | 11 | 0 | NULL |
| 08d87138-676a-48b8-85c0-4692d914fdf2 | 2021 | 11 | 0 | NULL |
| 08d87138-676a-48b8-85c0-4692d914fdf2 | 2021 | 11 | 0 | NULL |
| 08d87138-676a-48b8-85c0-4692d914fdf2 | 2021 | 11 | 0 | NULL |
| 08d87138-676a-48b8-85c0-4692d914fdf2 | 2021 | 11 | 0 | NULL |
| 08d87138-676a-48b8-85c0-4692d914fdf2 | 2021 | 11 | 0 | NULL |
| 08d87138-676a-48b8-85c0-4692d914fdf2 | 2021 | 11 | -0.09 | NULL |
| 08d87138-676a-48b8-85c0-4692d914fdf2 | 2021 | 11 | -3.07 | NULL |
| 08d87138-676a-48b8-85c0-4692d914fdf2 | 2021 | 11 | -0.61 | NULL |
| 08d87138-676a-48b8-85c0-4692d914fdf2 | 2021 | 11 | -20.86 | NULL |
| 08d87138-676a-48b8-85c0-4692d914fdf2 | 2021 | 11 | -0.22 | NULL |
| 08d87138-676a-48b8-85c0-4692d914fdf2 | 2021 | 11 | -2.05 | NULL |
| 08d87138-676a-48b8-85c0-4692d914fdf2 | 2021 | 11 | -0.29 | NULL |
| 08d87138-676a-48b8-85c0-4692d914fdf2 | 2021 | 11 | -2.6 | NULL |
| 08d87138-676a-48b8-85c0-4692d914fdf2 | 2021 | 11 | -0.19 | NULL |
| 08d87138-676a-48b8-85c0-4692d914fdf2 | 2021 | 11 | -2.5 | NULL |
| 08d87138-676a-48b8-85c0-4692d914fdf2 | 2021 | 11 | -0.34 | NULL |
| 08d87138-676a-48b8-85c0-4692d914fdf2 | 2021 | 11 | -4.65 | NULL |

How come when I add `ANY_VALUE(cte.ParentId)`, or `GROUP BY cte.ParentId`, the `SUM` becomes incorrect?

1. I do not expect `ANY_VALUE` to have any effect on aggregates, since the GROUP BY fields do not change. In fact, I would expect that changing or adding a field in the select list should not have an impact on one of the other selected fields.
2. `GROUP BY cte.ParentId` should not change the SUM since it is functionally dependent on `Id`.
3. Replacing `ANY_VALUE(cte.ParentId)` with `DEFAULT(cte.ParentId)` produces the correct result with correct SUMS (but then the `ParentId` column is all null)

Can someone help explain this behavior?

Comment: If I take the sample data you've provided in the last table (query result), I don't really see any difference in the `SUM()` either doing `GROUP BY ParentId` or `ANY_VALUE(ParentId)`.  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=de3247cded1c42d3fd5b6f64b55b432c . Makes me assume that it has something to do with the `JOIN`? or the `cte`?

Comment: If I change the last two `LEFT JOIN` to `JOIN`, then it seems to work. So the issue seems to be in the `LEFT JOIN`, but I'm not sure how it would make a difference. The `LEFT JOIN` should produce nulls in those columns and not make a difference in the sum

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve the issue, but I still don't fully understand why this worked.

I changed the last two `LEFT JOINS` to `JOINS` and then `SUM` worked correctly. So I assumed it might have been an issue with `COALESCE` since `LEFT JOIN` only affects the nullability of values.

I changed my expression from:

```
COALESCE(SUM(SR.AgencyProductionRevenue * SA.Split), 0) `TotalRevenue`
```

to:

```
SUM(COALESCE(SR.AgencyProductionRevenue, 0) * COALESCE(SA.Split, 0)) `TotalRevenue`
```

Now it works as expected.